# angular.js sets model to null when ng-options filtered

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a `course category` and `course` list select inputs. According to selected courses, I want to filter the `ng-options` so that user won't select same courses twice

```
  <td>
    <select ng-show="course._courseId" class="form-control" 
            ng-model="course.lookup_course_id" 
            ng-options="s.id as s.name for s in subcourses[course._courseId] | filter:notSelectedCourse">
      <option value="">Select Course</option>
    </select>
  </td>
```

And I'm using the following function to filter selected courses

```
$scope.notSelectedCourse = function(scourse) {
    if (!$scope.course_list)
      return true;

    for (var d, i = 0; i < $scope.course_list.length; i++) {
      d = $scope.course_list[i];
      if (d.lookup_course_id == scourse.id)
        return false;
    }

    return true;
};
```

However, angular.js doesn't update second selectbox value and update the model.

When I disable filter, it works fine but I need to add the filter so that user cannot select same course twice.

Here is the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/r3MPSmnug1w0y4lTwFch?p=preview), try to use select input

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you are expecting .....
Also did put the same constraint to the category selection
[demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/tkr4nWedY45eGn48aFtP/) http://embed.plnkr.co/tkr4nWedY45eGn48aFtP/

```
// This filter/predicate will invoked when select renders the options for each item in categories  ...
// If all course of the categerory has been selected
// then the options can be displayed. Else the option can be displayed to selected ....
$scope._filters.selectableCategories = function(selectedCategoryId) {
    return function(item) {         
        // 1. get the selected courses whose :
            // 1.1 course id is set/ NOT NULL... hence we ignore the courses that the user has not yet selected the course ...
            // 1.2 categerory == item
            // 1.3 categerory is not the current select category ... bcos the current selected category IS ALWAYS SELECTABLE ...    
        //2. If the above count  NOT EQUAL the course in category, then is selectable ...
        return $scope._courseList
            .filter(function(elm) { return elm._courseId && elm._categoryId !== selectedCategoryId && elm._categoryId === item.id;})
            .length != $scope._courses[item.id].length;
    }
}

// This filter/predicate will invoked when select renders the options for each item in courses_of_category  ...
// If the option has is not in the selected courses 
// then the options can be displayed. Else the option can be displayed to selected ....
$scope._filters.selectableCourses = function(selectedCategoryId, selectedCourseId) {
    return function(item) {
        // 1. get all the select courses :
            // 1.1 category === selected categerory
            // 1.2 course is not the selected course ... again bcos the current selected course IS ALWAYS SELECTABLE ...
        // 2. get the array of courseIds ...
        // 3. If item's id IS NOT IN the array, then item IS SELECTABLE ...
        return $scope._courseList
            .filter(function(elm) {return elm._categoryId == selectedCategoryId && elm._courseId !== selectedCourseId;})
            .map(function(elm){ return elm._courseId; })
            .indexOf(item.id) < 0;
    }
}
```